# How to return a List of objects in JSON when using JAX-RS

Tags: json, jboss7.x, resteasy

I have it working... kind of. Except when the Json is printed out, it prints out a lot of duplicate code. I suspect it has something to do with the way its marshalled. In any case, this is my code:

**User.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="user")

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="username", nullable=false)
    private String userName;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="phoneid", nullable=false)
    private String phoneid;

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToMany(
        cascade={CascadeType.ALL},
        mappedBy="voters",
        targetEntity=Vote.class,
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER

    )
    private List<Vote> votes = new ArrayList<Vote>();
```

**Vote.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="vote")
@Entity
@Table(name="votes")
public class Vote implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="max", nullable=false)
    private int max;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="current", nullable=false)
    private int current;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="is_simple", nullable=false)
    private int isSimple;

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity=User.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "vote_user",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "vote_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}
    )
    private List<User> voters = new ArrayList<User>();
```

**GetRestfulVote.java**

```
@Path("/votes")
public class GetRestfulVote {
    @EJB
    VoteBeanInterface bean;

    @GET
    @Path("/{userid}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Vote> getVotesJson(@PathParam("userid") String userId) {
        //Will be getting using the user id to be able to set a flag if the calling user voted in it
        List<Vote> listOfVotes = bean.getVotes();

        return listOfVotes;
    }

}
```

Now as is fairly obvious from my code I have a many to many relationship between my `Vote` and `User` classes. I believe thats where the issue is occurring. But the problem is I don't know how to keep it from being omitted from the "jsonification" process. More importantly, how can I force it only to turn the owning class list (`Votes`) into Json. Any help and clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: @Perception I am using the built in Javax-RS conversion. Depending on this line `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`, it can be either xml or json. So it turns java objects into json automatically.

Comment: there is no automatic conversion of Java objects to JSON without a JSON provider. It so happens that RESTEasy uses Jackson by default. Add a `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the users field in your votes class. That should get you what you need.

Comment: Oh really. I did not know it uses Jackson by default. Thanks for letting me know. And I appreciate the advice. I'll give it a try.